# how to use the condition field is null in Entity Framework Core (Oracle)

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to use the condition "field is null" in linq, I tried using "field == null" but it doesn't bring me the records.

```
var query = from p in _context.Product
where p.PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE == null
select new ProductViewModel { Id = p.PRODUCT_ID, name = p.PRODUCT_NAME };
```

I made this small subquery to understand why it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT count(1)
        FROM PRODUCTS
        WHERE PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE != NULL
) AS SYMBOL_OPERATOR1
,(SELECT count(1)
        FROM PRODUCTS
        WHERE PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE IS NULL
) AS SYMBOL_OPERATOR2
FROM DUAL
```

[image: query example]

is there any way to use "where field is null" in linq or to simulate it?

**librarys:**

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (version 6.0.8)
- Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore (version 6.21.61)

**UPDATE 1:**

I just checked the log, and it's printing the following when transforming to pl sql code

```
2022-10-06 17:36:53.0309|DEBUG|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|192.168.1.15|Generated query execution expression: 
'queryContext => new SingleQueryingEnumerable<ProductViewModel>(
    (RelationalQueryContext)queryContext, 
    RelationalCommandCache.SelectExpression(
        Projection Mapping:
            Id -> 0
            Name -> 1
        SELECT s.PRODUCT_ID AS Id, s.PRODUCT_NAME AS Name
        FROM PRODUCT AS s
        WHERE s.PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE == NULL), 
    Func<QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator, ProductViewModel>, 
    API.SGA.Products.Data.DbContext, 
    False, 
    False, 
    True
)'|
```

Comment: `where p.PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE == null` should work just fine. How are you confirming that you get no records? Are you actually materializing the query or just looking at it in the debugger?

Comment: When using databases replace null with DBNull.Value

Comment: Also you should not use `!= NULL` in SQL - you should use `IS NOT NULL`. `!= NULL` will return `NULL` which is not `true` (`NULL` is neither true nor false)

Comment: @DStanley I am executing my project,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your class's "PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE" attribute nullable? Something like

```
public int? PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE {get; set; }
```

Comment: Is your class's "PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE" attribute nullable?

Something like

`public int? PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE {get; set; }`

Comment: yes of course, that's why I attached an image where I make the select with different condition

Comment: your answer about the nullable field worked please edit your main comment to mark it as a solution, thanks.

Comment: ok, i already edited my main comment

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
where p.PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE.Equals(null)
```

in Linq?

In SQL it should be

```
WHERE PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I just tested your answer, I checked the log and it translates as  ` WHERE s.PRODUCT_IND_CHANGE == NULL`